# Is there a way to use the transactions in TCPDF when extending it with FPDI?

Tags: fpdf, tcpdf, fpdi

I am using TCPDF with FPDI's bridge. The issue I'm having is that as soon as I use the `startTransaction()` I get the following error:

```
TCPDF ERROR: Cannot access protected property FPDI:$numpages / Undefined property: FPDI::$numpages
```

and the script ends (because of the die in the TCPDF::Error() method).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->startTransaction();
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'blah blah blah');
$pdf->rollbackTransaction();

$pdf->Output( . time() . '.pdf', 'D');
```

If I change it to:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'blah blah blah');

$pdf->Output( . time() . '.pdf', 'D');
```

it works fine.

Is there anyway to make them work together and use TCPDF's transactions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I found was to to use [PHP's object cloning](http://php.net/clone) which allows me to do transactions and roll them back whenever I want. Here's an example:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'blah blah blah');

$_pdf = clone $pdf;

// do stuff that you may want to revert
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'PDFs suck!');

// revert the PDF
$pdf = $_pdf;

$pdf->Output( . time() . '.pdf', 'D');
```

The PDF will only contain "blah blah blah".

Answer (score 2):

in your first example you should use `$pdf = $pdf->rollbackTransaction` or `$pdf->rollbackTransaction(true)` instead of just `$pdf->rollabackTransaction()`

this is because *rollbackTransaction* takes a boolean parameter **(default is false)**, to know if it have to return the rollbackvalue (false) or set the object to the rollback state (true).

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf = new FPDI(); 

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->startTransaction(true);

$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'blah blah blah');

$pdf->rollbackTransaction(true);

$pdf->Output( . time() . '.pdf', 'D');
```

Adding **true** as parameter in the Transaction Method Calls solved the Problem for me.

Comment: I think this is only needed for rollbackTransaction.